# How can I request employer to release for necessary documents on the last working day

Tags: resignation, human-resources, india, relieving-letter

I have resigned from my current company last month. I spoke with my HR yesterday,  asked him that, "What documents would I get on the last working day?" He told, we'll send an exit mail which has all the details like your Joining date to last working date. After 15 days we'll do Full and Final settlement, we'll issue the relieving letter.

Here I have a problem, my new employer asked me to carry the following documents on the date of Joining.

1. Service certificate. **MANDATORY**
2. Relieving Letter. **MANDATORY**

But, my HR says we'll just send an exit email nothing more than that. After 15 days we'll issue relieving letter.

I am worried with this problem, can't understand how to deal the situation. Should I send an email to the following people?

TO: HR, HR ADMINS
CC: My Director, CTO
Subject:  Requesting for exit documents and experience letter on last working day.

---

I am sorry for the below negative questions that my mind is thinking infinitely and its questioning me, not allowing me to sleep atleast. I accept criticism for my negative questions.

- What if, he doesn't give my documents after 15 days. Is there any proof(written confirmation) that he would give in 15 days. If so, I can show the proof to new employer. Otherwise What? Asking him for proof is ethical doesn't it look cheap SRK?
- Is my current employer goal is to make me unemployed loosing this and that?
- Once after your last working day, you are out, What if there is a situation like "If you call them for documents and they are rejecting your call and not allowing you to get into office? Then what?
- If nothing worked then you'll be on road, having 3 years gap in career. You'd get some irrelevant(NON-white collar) jobs, your education over the years will be gone in vain and is trivial.

---

In fact, I have no experience understanding the exit processes, since this is my first company in my career. I am looking for guidance.

How can I ask my current employer politely and diplomatically to get my documents safely to my hand on the last working day? 
What should I do to be legally shielded to get the documents at-least after 15 days?

Comment: `How can I ask...?` - Why not just ask? // `How can I [force]...?` - That's either off-topic or opinion-based.

Comment: @JimG. I have asked them in person, they've mentioned to send 1 exit mail only.

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure: I don't live where you live, and have never heard of either of the documents you reference.  Things in the US are a bit more flexible.

Talk with your prospective new employer's HR department.  Tell them that you want to start the new job as soon as possible, explain your current employer's policy to them, and ask if they will accept a copy of the exit email, and let you get them copies of the documents as soon as you get them.

Worst case, you're going to take two weeks unpaid vacation, between your last day at your current employer and your start date at your new one.  If your financial situation is so dire that you can't miss even one paycheck, you have far bigger problems than just a paperwork scheduling issue.

Far more likely, your new employer will be willing to accept a printed copy of the exit email, and let you give them copies of the letters when you get them.

NOW, depending on where you live, there may be legal issues that prevent your new employer from making the above accommodation.  If that is the case, see previous paragraph about "two weeks vacation".  And consider emigrating to someplace that values workers and allows them to work freely.

Comment: The OP is from India (he has tagged India). This is a common situation in Indian IT scene. I suppose your advise "And consider emigrating to someplace that values workers and allows them to work freely." won't work.

Comment: @atur, with all due respect, with the number of Indian engineers I see in US companies, emigration is indeed a possibility.  If he doesn't want to come to the US (and, right now, I wouldn't blame him), competent IT people are in demand quite literally everywhere on the planet.

Comment: I commented based on OP's experience and premise that its not so easy to emigrate. Though I do accept that it is indeed an option for competent IT people.

Comment: Your comment about emigrating is entirely unnecessary. You cannot draw conclusions about an entire country based on one incident that one employee in one company reported. The vast majority of Indian companies that I have worked with (or know about through contacts) don't make the leaving employee jump through hoops on their way out. I have known people who requested their past employer for missing documents several months after leaving and got them promptly.

Comment: @MaskedMan according to _this site itself_ India has **huge** problems with this "relieving letter" utter nonsense. But… every country has its own huge problems here or there, so switching country merely means switching usual problems with new problems you aren't used to. Your mileage may vary. Objects in mirror are closer than it appears.

Comment: Relevant question on the nature of release letters:[What is a relieving letter? What are the consequences of not having one?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one). Seems that they are in fact commonly asked in Indian context, some places more than others. Some users seem to suggest that when unable to provide such letter, giving the contact of a previous coworker/manager could be an alternative to try