# Not getting the relieving letter. Need it urgently

Tags: human-resources, india, relieving-letter

I am facing a difficult situation. I worked in a company for above a year. In July, last year, I resigned from the company to pursue my higher education plans. Due to my highly hectic schedule and exams nearing by, I asked them to relieve me early. My notice period was of 3 months and I agreed to serve for 1 month. Initially, they agreed as I have been doing some good things in the company but suddenly 2 days before my relieving date, they said that i need to serve my notice period for 3 months. I was very disappointed, and I complained.

My manager was very supportive and advised me to leave the company saying that they will give you the relieving letters later. give them some time to cool down. Not thinking much, I dropped and email and quit my job. Since then, i have not received any relieving letters from them and when asked about the same, they are very rude in replying.

Now I have got admission in one of the premier MBA institute and they are asking for my experience and relieving letters which I have to submit by june. What should I Do?

Some other details:
1) They did not pay me for the last month which was approximately equal to the amount I need to pay if I dont serve the notice period.
2) My employment agreement just says one sentence about this "Your notice period is 3 months" and nothing else that what If I cant serve.
3) My manager is still supportive and can give me in written
4) I am carrying my joining letter, salary slips and promotion letter which I got a month before resigning.

Please help me friends. MBA is really important for me.

Comment: Related Question: [How can I request employer to release for necessary documents on the last working day](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14698/how-can-i-request-employer-to-release-for-necessary-documents-on-the-last-workin)

Answer (score 3):

I will give you options here.

**option one:**

You can get a lawyer and send a legal notice claiming your relieve and your experience letter and also damages for the delay for irresponsible behavior of the company in addressing the grievance of the former employee.

**option two**

The problem that you have is that your resignation is not getting accepted by your current organization. You should check your offer letter and that would clearly state your notice period. If your manager does not waive it off, then you will have to fully serve the notice period. The organization is bound by the rules as stated in the offer letter to you.

Talk to your manager, **he is the best bet here to solve the problem**. I'd suggest you contact your Manager and see what can be done to get the relieving letter.

Probably they might ask you pay for the skipped notice period (if your notice period is X days, the amount will typically be basic pay component of your salary for X days).

While you might have genuine reasons for not serving the notice period, its better to pay for the notice period and get the relieving document.

Comment: actually I have a question for you. The answer/advise you have given here is good. Question : Have you even known these advise to work (particularly Option one).

Comment: It would work but also depends upon the country and how much the law favors towards common man.

Comment: That is why I asking would it work in India/or had you known it to work (OP is also from India)

Comment: @atur: gonna take time considering india, but surely it would work... but have patience... you know about our country where for serious offense it takes yrs to get a judgement.

Comment: :)  nice to see the optimism

Answer (score -1):

No company has to give you a relieving letter, it's just the tactful thing to do when leaving under amicable circumstances. Technically, you did violate the terms of your employment, as you departed earlier than what you agreed to, and thus I would not call your departure an amicable circumstance.

It sounds like your best bet is to try to work with your former manager (since you say he's still supportive) in order to get some sort of recommendation letter, which you can present to the MBA school.

Comment: Actually in India there are regulations about this and yes a company is required to provide a relieving letter once an employee's obligation to the company is fulfilled and the employee is terminated.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame - Can you please point/link me to some of these regulations regarding relieving letter.