# How can I explain to potential employers that I am unable to provide a relieving letter?

Tags: india, relieving-letter

The company I currently work for expects a minimum of two years of service in the organisation, although there is no clause in the contract that enforces this.

Working for this company is now causing issues for my health and I have decided to leave the company, however my employer refuses to provide a relieving letter as this two years minimum was not met.

How can I explain to future potential employers why I am unable to provide a reference / relieving letter from this company?

Comment: @Rachcha because this sort of issue is considerably different in countries such as India who have a relieving letter as a much more formalized part of their job application process (compared to say, the United States or Europe). This context matters for purposes of this question. For those unfamiliar, see [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20945/2322) to learn what a relieving letter is.

Comment: Read your contract. If there is no binding in the contract, he cannot hold you back from leaving. In case you have a doubt, hire a lawyer for the same. There are no government bindings on private firms in India. Hence, your contract is the only obligation you have.

Comment: Is there a way to get proper relieving letter. I'm ready to serve the notice period.

Comment: Related Question 1: [What are the consequences of not having a relieving letter](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20945/16)

Comment: Related Question 2: [How can I request employer to release for necessary documents on the last working day](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/14698/16)

Comment: Related Question 3: [Not getting the relieving letters. Need it urgently](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20922/16)

Comment: Do you have a written bond with the employer?

Comment: Related, more recent question: [Can I join without release letter as I was sick to serve notice period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/106201/can-i-join-without-release-letter-as-i-was-sick-to-serve-notice-period)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your country. I'm from Indonesia so it's probably not much different. In my country, if you're a fresh graduate with 2 years of  experience, they rarely ask for references. Sure, references will boost your chances of getting hired but they are not always necessary.

My suggestion is just send out your resume or CV. If they ask you for references, you may give your coworker/manager phone number hoping that they explain your problem and that give you a good reference.

Comment: I'm from India. Is it acceptable to give coworker number as reference. Since most of the companies expects HR reference in india.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to talk with your present HR management. Take advice from them regarding it. If they are unable to solve your issue, then take help of workers union. My father-in-law resides at Bangalore, India, there company do have a employee union. I hope this would help you.

Comment: this totally ignores the fact that asker already spoke to present HR management: "my employer refuses to provide a relieving letter as this two years minimum was not met"