# Can I get the relieving letter from a previous employer, two years after resigning?

Tags: job-change, india, relieving-letter

I worked for my previous employer (Company X) for 8 months. I served the notice period and was given a provisional relieving letter at the end. My current employer (Company Y) was ok with the provisional relieving letter, and did not insist on the permanent relieving letter. Hence, I did not bother collecting it from Company X.

Now, 2 years later, I have got an offer from another company (Company Z), and I would resign from Company Y. Company Z has asked for relieving letters from all the previous employers. I fear that it is too late and they would not provide me the letter 2 years later.

- Can I get the permanent relieving letter from Company X, if I ask them now?
- Will not having a permanent relieving letter affect my employment with other companies in future?
- Will I be able to manage with the provisional relieving letter?
- Will Company Z accept my provisional relieving letter?

Comment: Related questions, not dupes: "[How can I explain to potential employers that I am unable to provide a relieving letter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21372/how-can-i-explain-to-potential-employers-that-i-am-unable-to-provide-a-relieving)" and "[What is a relieving letter? What are the consequences of not having one?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one?noredirect=1&lq=1)"

Comment: Before anyone starts, this is not off-topic for company-specific or legal questions, so don't even.  An HR pro should be able to help this (with relevant Indian experience of course)

Comment: @ChristopherEstep Thanks for keeping this question open. Otherwise I could not have answered it. :-)

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. 3. May Be, 4. Can't tell (In order of the questions asked)

Comment: @ChristopherEstep, how is the last question not company-specific? I am just trying to understand the guidelines here.

Comment: @PagMax See my answer. Sometimes you have to give the OP what they want rather than what they have asked. :)

Comment: @MaskedMan, I did see your answer earlier and upvoted. I agree with your answer as well as your comment! Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6):

**Always keep all your documents in order, whether you need them immediately or not.**

Let this be a learning experience. From now on, insist on all documents, either in physical or electronic form. Then keep them organized so that you can find them easily when you need them next.

> Can I get the relieving letter from a previous employer, two years after resigning?

I recommend that you ask.  Most reputed employers store employee records and documents electronically. They can print a document and sign it without much hassle. If your Company X is not one of them, you will have to chase some people to dig out old records.

They would certainly ask you the reason for delay in collecting the document. Just tell them the truth instead of creative lies.

> Will not having a permanent relieving letter affect my employment with other companies in future?

This would cause you some inconvenience, but is unlikely to create any problems.

Many companies now ask for relieving letters from all previous employers. They will ask you why you have only a provisional relieving letter. Some may ask you more questions, or for additional documents.

> Will I be able to manage with the provisional relieving letter?

You can "manage" if you are ok with some hassles. I do not expect a company to take extreme actions like withdrawing the offer or firing the employee for having only a provisional relieving letter.

> Will Company Z accept my provisional relieving letter?

Each company has its own policies to deal with the situation. Some companies may ignore it (especially for an employment that last only 8 months), others may ask you lots of questions or do additional background checks. Some may ask you to sign a declaration or affidavit. We cannot tell what the specific Company Z would do.

**Go get that relieving letter now, whatever it takes.**

- The more you delay it, the more awkward it gets to explain the delay, so don't wait until the next time.
- Getting the relieving letter now will save you from all the future what-ifs.
- When you do not have the relieving letter from the immediately previous employer, you can reasonably say, "I have not got it yet". 2 years later, you can no longer say that with a straight face. :-)

Comment: @ritika You are welcome. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask on this site. By the way, if the answer helped you, you might want to accept it by clicking the check mark. If you want to wait for more answers, that is cool too.