# Who can sign a Relieving Letter?

Tags: new-job, job-change, india, relieving-letter

I am currently at notice period and my employment will be ending at this weekend. My notice period is ending at 17th and I have to join on 19th in new company. My CEO is currently out of country and will not be present in office until the 20th. In my office, CEO normally signs on relieving letter.

What positions are normally accepted as being able to sign a relieving letter?

Comment: Surely there's someone in the company who can act in the place of the CEO when he's not available. If the CEO was in hospital for 2 weeks, would the company grind to a halt?

Comment: Unfortunetely not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I request employer to release for necessary documents on the last working day](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14698/how-can-i-request-employer-to-release-for-necessary-documents-on-the-last-workin)

Comment: Hey @Chad, this is a different question from the linked duplicate. That one is asking what to do if an employer doesn't send it as promised, this one is asking what to do if the CEO is not available to issue the letter (and what alternatives to having the CEO provide one there may be).

Comment: Yes I want to know the alternatives. Is it OK to having sign of Project Manager on the papers?

Comment: @jmac I edited the question to focus exclusively on who can sign the letter.  I think it is acceptable now unless the OP rejects it.

Comment: Head HR, CEO, Managing director can sign the relieving letter.

Comment: Pretty sure the HR can sign it off. My Relieving letter was signed by the head HR.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the next person in the chain of command. They would logically have the authority to handle this while the CEO is away